# Recompiling TeeChartPro

Tags: delphi, teechart

I would like to build and install the TeeChartPro source code in Delphi 10 Seattle. I have TeeChartSourceCode Build 2014.12.140923.
When I execute TeeRecompile there is no IDE's.
What can I do? It seams that my TeeRecompiler only looks for delphi up to XE7.
Is there a possibility to get an updated TeeRecompile?

Thanks, 
Jens

Answer (score 1):

When v2014.12 was published RAD Studio 10 Seattle still didn't exist.
TeeChart v2015.16 was the first version to support RAD Studio 10 Seattle.
See the Release Notes [here](https://steema.com/version_info/vcl).

Comment: Sorry, I pressed the wrong button. Of cource I could buy the last version but v2014.12 cover my needs.When I bought the sourcecode I expected that I could recompile the code. When TeeRecompile cannot compile the "old" source in 10 Seattle, is it then a possibility to manually compile the source?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to compile the v2014.12 packages with RAD 10 Seattle. You can copy the TeePro921 and DclTeePro921 (.dpk and .res), rename them from 21 to 23 and edit them with notepad or similar to correct the references. Then you should be able to compile the packages (first the TeePro23 and DclTeePro23 after it). However, you'll probably find errors because the v2014.12 sources aren't adapted to the changes that IDE added.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at .inc file (TeeDefs.inc may be) for version depended conditional defines.

For minimum changings, add at first lines line like that:

```
{$IFDEF VER300} {$DEFINE VER280} {$ELSE} {$ENDIF}
```

it will define VER280 (from Delphi XE7) under Delphi 10 Seattle (wich implictly defines VER300)

Comment: Thank you Nashev, that helped me a lot but now I struggles with the prefix/namespace “VCLTee.”
I have tried to insert it in: “Project/Options/Descriptions/LIB prefix” but it does not help, any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't ever need to use this prefixes. Do not use them at all